# Provide file's thumbnail from a different file

Tags: thumbnails, dokan

I've been trying to save the thumbnails for the files separately, so that when the OS will call ReadFile() to load the thumbnail, it will be loaded from an additional file, instead of the original file.

My question is if this is even possible. Can I recognize when the OS is requesting the thumbnail (between all the ReadFile() calls that it makes, with different offsets and buffer sizes) and deliver it from a different file?

Also, can I disable the requests for a thumbnail and deliver it in a different manner, instead? I want to reduce the number of ReadFile() calls that the OS makes for a file and just receive ReadFile() requests when I actually open the file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not the OS that requests thumbnails but Explorer, which is just a regular application. Explorer can open files for many purposes and there's no good way to distinguish when it reads thumbnails or any other metainformation. Neither there's a way to turn off tumbnails for a specific drive.